# Confused with Marginal Distribution Function Question

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the joint density function:

$$f(x,y) = \frac{32}{7}xy,\, 0 \leq x \leq 1,\, 0 \leq y \leq 1,\, y > \frac{1}{2}x$$

and $0$ otherwise.

Find $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ (the two marginal distribution functions.)

The sketch I made resembled an upside down triangle hugging the $y$-axis and going along $y = \frac{1}{2}x$, and then a rectangle from $x = 0$ to $1$ above it.

Assuming my sketch was right, my bounds for my marginal distribution functions were as follows:

For $f_X(x)$ it was $y = (1/2)x$ to $y = 1$, and for $f_Y(y)$ it was $x = 0$ to $x = 2y$. $f_X(x)$ turned out fine when eventually having to compute $E[X]$ and $Var[X]$ but no matter how I change the bounds for $f_Y(y)$ I keep getting an answer that doesn't make sense when I calculate the $E[Y]$ and $Var[Y]$ (negative).

I need some help.

Comment: The direction looks correct from your description, despite the sudden introduction of dummy variables $m$ and $n$. You should show your calculation and see which part goes wrong.

Comment: $f(x,y)$ isn't a probability mass function; it needs to be normalised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that $\int_0^1\int_{x/2}^1 xy\operatorname d y\operatorname d x = 7/32$, so you don't have a proper pdf.   Should it be normalised (as below) or did you quote the wrong support?

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \tfrac {32}7 xy~\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x\leqslant 1, x/2<y, 0\leqslant y\leqslant 1}$$

---

> For $f_X(x)$ it was $n=(1/2)m$ to $n=1$, and for $f_Y(y)$ it was $m=0$ to $m=2n$.

Not sure why you switched from $x,y$ to $n,m$, but if you mean:

$$\begin{align}f_X(m) ~&=~ \int_{m/2}^{1} f_{X,Y}(m, n)\operatorname d n \\[2ex] f_Y(n) ~&=~ \int_0^{2n} f_{X,Y}(m,n) \operatorname d m\end{align}$$

Then that is mostly okay, *however*, keep in mind that the joint support will be $$0\leqslant \underline{m\leqslant 1}\,, \underline{m<2n}\,, 0\leqslant \underline{n\leqslant 1}$$

That will make the marginal density functions :

$$\begin{align}f_X(m) ~&=~ \mathbf 1_{0\leqslant m\leqslant 1}\cdot\int_{m/2}^1 \tfrac{32}7\,m\,n\operatorname d n \\ &= ~ \tfrac 47 m(4-m^2)\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant m\leqslant 1} \\[2ex] f_Y(n) ~&=~ \mathbf 1_{0\leqslant n\leqslant 1}\cdot\int_0^{\min\{2n, 1\}} \tfrac{32}7\,m\,n\operatorname d m \\[1ex] &=~ \mathbf 1_{0\leqslant n< 1/2}\cdot\int_0^{2n} \tfrac{32}7\,m\,n\operatorname d m+\mathbf 1_{1/2\leqslant n\leqslant 1}\cdot\int_0^1 \tfrac{32}7\,m\,n\operatorname d m \\ &=~ \tfrac{64}7\, n^3\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant n < 1/2}+\tfrac{16}7\, n\,\mathbf 1_{1/2\leqslant n\leqslant 1}\end{align}$$

So $\mathsf E(Y) = \int_0^{1/2}\tfrac{64}7\, n^4\,\mathrm d n + \int_{1/2}^1 \frac{16}7\, n^2\,\mathrm d n \\ \mathsf E(Y^2) = \int_0^{1/2}\tfrac{64}7\, n^5\,\mathrm d n + \int_{1/2}^1 \frac{16}7\, n^3\,\mathrm d n$

Comment: This was quite helpful. Does the logic pertaining to the bounds of $f_Y(y)$ (yes y=n) apply to the expectation value for Y or just the simple from 0 - 1 since those are the "extreme values"?

Comment: Yes that was a misquote it is in fact $\frac{32}{7}xy$

Comment: @user3002545 the expectation is the sum of integrals over the two pieces of the density function (see the append).